# Rails query of parent model doesn't retrieve child models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-5

I have parent and child models on rails 5 with mongoid. When I query the parent, with `.includes` command - I can see rails trying to query mongo db - but the result json does not return the child objects.

Parent Model:

```
class Activity
   include Mongoid::Document
   field :title, type: String

   has_many :activity_pictures
end
```

Child Model:

```
class ActivityPicture
   include Mongoid::Document
   field :name, type: String
   belongs_to :activity, :class_name => 'Activity'
end
```

The controller methods:

```
def index
     @activities = Activity.includes(:activity_pictures).all
end

def show
     Activity.includes(:activity_pictures)
end
```

off course, I have updated activity_params:

```
def activity_params
    params.require(:activity).permit(:title, :activity_pictures)
end
```

How do i get the full json data from http://localhost:3000/activities.json and the single object links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst the associations are being loaded with the use of `includes`, you need to specifically call the loaded association in order for it to render. Try

```
def index
  @activities = Activity.includes(:activity_pictures).all
  render json: @activities, include :activity_pictures
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above by margo was the right lead. I am using jbuilder though, so the solution was to change the file

> index.json.jbuilder

as follows:

```
json.array! @activities do |activity|
    json.title activity.title
    json.activity_pictures activity.activity_pictures do |activity_picture|
       json.name activity_picture.name
  end
end
```